# Convert scalar UDF in select to table valued function

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, query-optimization, user-defined-functions

I have 2 tables. Table 1 (DateTable) contains dates and item names, table 2 (PriceTable) contains prices over time and dates that the price changed.

Table 1 ( DateTable)

```
| itemName |   Date   |
|    A     | 2012-8-22|
|    A     | 2012-9-2 |
```

Table 2 ( PriceTable)

```
| Update Date | Price|itemName|
|  2012-7-1   | 5.00 |   A    |
|  2012-8-1   | 5.50 |   A    |
|  2012-9-1   | 6.00 |   A    |
```

My task is, given a date, I want to determine what the price of the item was on that date.

I'm currently doing this with a scalar function, which is really slow. Is there a way I could rewrite this, either as a table valued function or using something else that will help speed this up a bit? I've been staring at this for awhile now to no avail.

My current queries:

```
select
    d.date
    ,dbo.fn_GetPrice(d.date, 'A')
from DateTable d
where d.itemName = 'A'
```

and function

```
alter function fn_GetPrice(@date DateTime, @itemName varchar(50))
returns int
as
begin
declare @price int
    select @price = p.price
    from PriceTable p
    where p.itemName = @itemName
        and p.updateDate = (select MAX(p2.updateDate)
            from PriceTable p2
            where p2.updateDate < @date
                and p2.itemName = @itemName)
return @price
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would this work?  Replacing the `udf` with just a `join`?

```
select
    d.date,
    p.Price
from 
    DateTable d 
    join PriceTable p
        on p.itemName = d.itemName
        and p.updateDate = (
            select max(p2.updateDate)
            from PriceTable p2
            where 
                p2.updateDate < d.date
                and p2.itemName = p.itemName
        )
where d.itemName = 'A'
```